# How to parse a full set of formula chain from an excel?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have an excel file that has a complex calculation model, the performance of direct using apache POI is not acceptable to me. therefore I am thinking to extract the full set formula chain and parse it to java.

for example: If C1=A1+B1 and A1=A2+B2, B1=A3+B3 => C1 = A2+B2+A3+B3

I also noticed that there is an object called CalculationChain, it seems there is a convenient way to get the formula chain. rather than parse these nested Cells one by one.

Anyone can give an example to shed some light on?

Comment: I doubt someone will be able to answer this. If the question would be "What is the calculation chain in Excel and how does it work?", that would be answerable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-calculation-chain#calculation-cell-class and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.calculationcell?view=openxml-2.8.1.

Comment: Also, Office Open XML files are simply ZIP files. So you can unzip them and have a look at `/xl/calcChain.xml`. Then you will get an idea about what this provides to you. Nothing really helpful in my opinion. But see yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good answer, but it moves one step forward.

```
XSSFEvaluationWorkbook xssfEvaluationWorkbook = XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create(workbook);
Ptg[] ptg = FormulaParser.parse(cell.getCellFormula(), xssfEvaluationWorkbook, FormulaType.NAMEDRANGE, sheetIndex);
```

Comment: It moves one step forward to what? Parsing the formula into `p`arse-`t`hin`g`s is exactly what `apache poi` also does while formula evaluation. So what advantage do you think to have now?

Comment: I intended to translate the excel formula into java code. for example, if there are Ref tokens such as RefPtg or Ref3DPxg. I will parse them further, until fully resolved.

Comment: But this is exactly what `apache poi` also does while formula evaluation. So I doubt you will do that "better" in sense of more performant. The parsing is not the performance bottleneck. The performance bottleneck is how `apache poi` stores `XSSFCell` data in memory. The `XML` gets fully parsed into `ooxml-schema` objects first. Then those `ooxml-schema` objects get wrapped using `XSSF` objects. So the memory is filled with objects. That's the problem.

Comment: There is misunderstanding, the excel formulas will be parsed once into Java functions in compile phase( might be automatically or semi-automatically), then only the Java function will be used to take input and do calculation to produce output. I want to not use excel to do calculations but use  it as a formula template only.